# Changing CSS class with javascript id messes up with CSS styling?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I m trying to make an HTML responsive webpage with cards that flip 180 degrees when you click them and after I changed the div class with an id for onclick event my CSS styling messed up and put the cards randomly on the screen.
How can I fix this?

I tried to copy the styling of the CSS class to the id styling but that destroys the animation.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {     //all of the divs are in a container div
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.card-flip, #misto1, #misto2, ....{
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.card-flip-faces, #misto1, #misto2,.... {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
          transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
.card-flip .card-flip-faces   {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
          transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.card-flip-front, .card-flip-back {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.card-flip-front  {
  display: block;
  color: #11998e;
  background-color: white;
}
.card-flip-back  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #11998e;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
          transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card-flip-icon {
  font-size: 600%;
}
.card-flip-title {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .card-flip {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-flip {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card-flip {
    width: calc(33.33% - 2rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- This is how all of my divs look like -->

<div id="misto1" onclick="handler_click1()"> <!--before id it was class="card-flip-->
  <div class="card-flip-faces">
   <div class="card-flip-front">
                <i class="card-flip-icon fas fa-flask"></i>
    <h4 class="card-flip-title">Title</h4>
    <p class="card-flip-text">Some text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-flip-back">
    <i class="card-flip-icon fas fa-flask"></i>
    <h4 class="card-flip-title">Hemoleucograma</h4>
    <p class="card-flip-text"> Another fancy text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="misto2" onclick="handler_click2()">
  <div class="card-flip-faces">
   <div class="card-flip-front">
                <i class="card-flip-icon fas fa-flask"></i>
    <h4 class="card-flip-title">Title</h4>
    <p class="card-flip-text">Some text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-flip-back">
    <i class="card-flip-icon fas fa-flask"></i>
    <h4 class="card-flip-title">Hemoleucograma</h4>
    <p class="card-flip-text"> Another fancy text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- this is the script for the onclick animation -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var x=0;
    function handler_click1(){
        
        if(x==0){
            document.getElementById('misto1').className ='card-flip';
            x=1;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('misto1').className ='card-flip-faces';
            x=0;
            
        }
    
    }
        
    function handler_click2(){
        
        if(x==0){
            document.getElementById('misto2').className ='card-flip';
            x=1;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('misto2').className ='card-flip-faces';
            x=0;
            
        }
    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're changing the class for `<div id="misto1"`, however you'll probably want to change the class for `<div class="card-flip-faces">` inside instead, I guess?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3beqzj74/

Comment: You do not need to create *unique* click handlers for each card, but rather a single click handler that will be applied to all cards (preferably a delegated handler) and toggle a class when clicked.

Comment: @ChrisG I don t understand how you did that because in my HTML code it doesn't t do anything

Comment: I changed some CSS lines, too; did you use all of the fiddle's code? Anyway, if you want help with code, please put it in the question.

Comment: I changed too. Thank you! Now I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intended method of adding and removing specific classes is to use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which supports the `.add`, `.remove`, and `.toggle` methods.

These methods can even be overloaded with additional string arguments to alter multiple classes at once. Using the `toggle` method, your use case could be as trivial as:

```
document.getElementById("misto1").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("flipOver");
    // Where .flipOver is a class that rotates 180deg around the y-axis.
});
```

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/8dc0nmsf/7/) of this in action using your code. I changed as little as possible, so there's still a decent amount of refactoring that needs to be done.

Comment: Saved my life man, thank you so much! I just added the class and the id and now the styling is like I wanted to be!

Comment: @Noobatthis No problem. Like the comments say, you should only need to create one event listener in total, regardless of the number of cards you create. It's bad practice to use inline events like `onclick=...`, as well. Reading about [event delegation](https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/) will likely be helpful, too.